# Lots of android gradle Flavors are almost same with only a little different of manifestPlaceholders

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have a lot of flavors(almost 50)  in my android project, when I build the project It costs about 30 minutes to package all the apks. But the apks are almost the same, the only difference between them is only one manifestPlaceholder value.
This is some of the code in my gradle file:

```
productFlavors {
    ltest {}
    demo {}
    C91zhushou {}
    C360sousuo {}
    C360yyy {}
    baidusousuo {}
    wandoujia1 {}
    weibotuiguang {}
    sougousousuo {}
    meizu {}
    yidong {}
    liantong {}
    mumayi {}
    wangyi {}
    leshangdian {}
    sohu {}
    youyi {}
    samsung {}
    wandoujia {}
    lg {}
    nearme {}
    ppzhushou {}
    sougou {}
    suning {}
    liqu {}
    yiyonghui {}
    taobao {}
    huawei {}
    jrtt1 {}
    jrtt2 {}
    yiming1 {}
    yiming2 {}
    yiming3 {}
    wap {}
    web {}
    anzhuo {}
    qihu {}
    yingyongbao {}
    xiaomi {}
    anzhi {}
    yingyonghui {}
    jifeng {}
    baidu {}
    googleplay {}
    jiangsudianxin {}
    baiduCPT {}
}
 productFlavors.all {
    flavor ->
        if (flavor.name.startsWith('C')) {
            flavor.manifestPlaceholders = [CHANNEL_CODE_VALUE: name.substring(1), TD_CHANNEL_ID_VALUE: name.substring(1)]
        } else {
            flavor.manifestPlaceholders = [CHANNEL_CODE_VALUE: name, TD_CHANNEL_ID_VALUE: name]
        }
}
```

As you can see, only the *CHANNEL_CODE_VALUE* is different.

Before I ask this question,I searched 'android gradle package process' and got [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/sdk/installing/studio-build.html)
And I think maybe the process can be improved.

Comment: Why do you need so many flavors if the only difference is the one value?  Wouldn't two flavors do the job?

Comment: First ,Happy to get your reply，the reason is I need to publish my app in those app store.

Comment: @ghuizhang have you tried [Buck](https://buckbuild.com/)? It's a fast performing build tool developed by a team at facebook. Give it a try; let me know.

Comment: @Chris ditto. Anyways a bit of parallel builds can do the trick if the OP is interested to get his hands dirty :D

Comment: @beerBear thanks,I'll have a try,And I'll let you know the result

Comment: @beerBear I have tried ,with a lot of error with buck.I'll try figured it out later.

Comment: @ghuizhang nice to hear, keep us posted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding each flavor is an independent gradle task.  Android studio runs them serially.  You might be able to speed up the process a little if you run gradle from the command line and have multiple tasks going at the same time - but as far as getting gradle to re-use the intermediate code that doesn't change between the flavors, I don't think it can do that or at least not easily - you could maybe figure out how to copy the intermediate files into the other flavor build path and trick it into thinking it doesn't need to build those again because they didn't change - but that's probably more trouble than it's worth.  For something this complex and specialized I'd hit up the gradle forums directly: https://discuss.gradle.org/